# Percentage (volume ratio) of 2 colors in Texture

Tags: python

Assuming that the total volume of a cube = 1, in the case of a single color V = 1.

In the case of two colors: if the volume V1 of Color 1 and V2 for the Color 2, then:

`V1 + V2 = 1 = V => If V1 = F then V2 = 1 - F`

Is it possible to create a cube with a volume texture (procedurale) with this relationship F with is using a python script

[image]

I want to use the percentage (volume ratio) of colors in Texture.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to feed that parameter F into a formula, and get a random pattern which covers exactly the amount of F in black? But what should the texture look like? Otherwise you could simply use a colorramp node to fulfill the formula...

Comment: If I use a musgrave texture, how I can use Colormap, are you any example? are you a example?